# Caching PHP POST data in HTML5 app cache from mobile device with no connectivity

Tags: php, javascript, ios, html, web-applications

This question may be a little generalised, but I'd like to get some ideas on how to go about this.

Basically I've developed a hybrid iOS app where the iOS end of it is simply a UIWebView with some extra bolt ons that get data from various parts of the UI webview and display them to the user in different ways.

The application allows you to update real time states of various things, so there is a drop down menu that has options like:

```
 Empty
 Full
 Unavailable
```

The problem is that in the environment that this is now being used in there is very patchy cellular connection and no wireless networking. So what I would like to do is for the web app to check wether or not there is connectivity and if there isn't to cache the data locally. I believe I can do this with the HTML5 app cache? And then when there is connectivity again I'd like it to check the cache file for new data and submit it.

Is this possible or do I need to look elsewhere? If it is possible, Does anybody have any advice or tips to help? Your help/advice is much appreciated.

EDIT:

Alternatively is there a way for me to grab AJAX POST data from within the UIWebView and then store it so I can submit it when the application finds connectivity again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've since worked out how to grab POST data out of a UIWebView so I should now be able to store that data in CoreData and then use javascript to execute some objective C to post the data out of CoreData to the database.